# Enable/disable windows-update from a vbscript

Tags: windows-services, vbscript

I need to disable windows-update service from my installation. I already use vbscript to do some stuff so I would like to do it in vbscript.

My knowledge of vbscript (or any other script language) is very limited so...can anybody help me out with that? I'll really appreciate it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Tomalak and Patrick Cuff. I really appreciate your help. I think this could be a good and complete answer.

Method 1: prevents the "Automatic Updates" service from starting automatically when the machine boots.

```
strComputer = "."  'could be any computer, not just the local one '
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colServiceList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Service where Name = 'wuauserv'")

For Each objService in colServiceList
  objService.ChangeStartMode("Disabled")
Next
```

Method 2: changes the "Automatic Updates" configuration from "Automatic" to "Turn off Automatic Updates". (MSDN lists [the other NotificationLevel constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385806(VS.85).aspx))

```
Const AU_DISABLED = 1

Set objAutoUpdate = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
Set objSettings = objAutoUpdate.Settings

objSettings.NotificationLevel = AU_DISABLED
objSettings.Save
```

In both cases you won't get automatic updates. With method 1 won't start while with method 2 the service is still running, just not doing anything.

You can do both of these things through the GUI:

- Method 1: Administrative Tools\Services\Automatic Updates, change "Startup type" from "Automatic" to "Disabled".
- Method 2: Control Panel\Automatic Updates, select "Turn off Automatic Updates".

Comment: Anyway I can not set this answer as the accepted one...I suppose it's because is mine and I am the one who make the question.

Comment: Javier, maybe you can't accept this unti it gets an up vote. Also, you have the descirption of Answer 1 and Answer 2 backwords ;)

Comment: Ops, copy&paste mistake!
I don't think not having votes is the problem...I can't not accept my other answer either and it has a vote. If somwbody ever vote this one up it'll check it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Tomalak.

I also found that:

```
Const SCHEDULED_INSTALLATION = 1

Set objAutoUpdate = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
Set objSettings = objAutoUpdate.Settings

objSettings.NotificationLevel = SCHEDULED_INSTALLATION
objSettings.Save
```

This is the link: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/tales/sg0705.mspx

Comment: I'd say your solution is "better" because it's a little more readable (I'd add a comment that SCHEDULED_INSTALLATION = 1 means "disabled").

Comment: This code does not disable the auto update service, but something *entirely different*. This code is better in the same way as black shoes are better than brown jackets.

Comment: True, but the net effect is the same.

Comment: Ok. So could you explain me what this code do??? As you can see I don't know how this works and I'd like to.

Comment: The code above changes the "Automatic Updates" service from "Automatic" to "Turn off Automatic Updates". The code below tells the "Automatic Updates" service to start automatically when the machine boots (change "Automatic" to "Disabled" below to stop the service and prvent it from starting)

Comment: (continued) In both cases you won't get automatic updates. With the code below (revised to "Disabled") the service won't start while with the code above the service is still running, just not doing anything.

Comment: You can do both of these things through the GUI. Code above = Control Panel\Automatic Updates, select "Turn off Automatic Updates". Code below = Administrative Tools\Services\Automatic Updates, change "Startup type" from "Automatic" to "Disabled".

Comment: Ok. Understood! Thanks for the explanation...unfortunately I can not grade your comments up!

Comment: No problem, you caught your own fish anyway?

You could edit your answer with Tomalak's response below, along with the explanation of what each does, and accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use VBScript, use WMI:

```
strComputer = "."  'could be any computer, not just the local one '
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colServiceList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Service where Name = 'wuauserv'")

For Each objService in colServiceList
  objService.ChangeStartMode("Disabled")
Next
```

Look into [the documentation of the WMI Win32_Service Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384896(VS.85).aspx) to find out what else might be doable.

Easier would be the use of `sc.exe`:

```
sc config wuauserv start=auto
```

Here is an excerpt of what `sc.exe` can do:

```
C:\>sc config
Modifies a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
SYNTAX:
sc <server> config [service name] <option1> <option2>...
CONFIG OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
 type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec|adapt>
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled>
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>
```

Comment: It should be. Try it.

Comment: Windows 10 does some crazy, outright hostile stuff when it comes to how Windows update works. It will silently re-enable disabled services, it will prevent services from being disabled, it will go out of its way to force you to install updates if you want or not. Every Windows 10 version comes up with new bullshit. There is a lot of stuff  to read on the topic. I can only suggest you read into the topic - I wish you luck, but I can't really give you interactive support on that in the comments.

Comment: I don't know. And it's possible that any solution you find online only works for a certain Windows 10 version. I have had success in preventing unwanted reboots using https://www.udse.de/en/windows-10-reboot-blocker. Try it out.

Comment: Thank you. In windows home gpedit do not exist so, FYI - 1) https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+get+gpedit+on+windows+10+Home/102025 2) https://gadgets.ndtv.com/laptops/features/how-to-disable-windows-10-automatic-updates-728049